# Memory-mapping huge files in Java

Tags: java, nio, memory-mapped-files

Is it possible to memory-map huge files (multiple GBs) in Java?

This method of `FileChannel` looks promising:

```
MappedByteBuffer map(FileChannel.MapMode mode, long position, long size)
```

Both `position` and `size` allow for 64-bit values -- so far, so good.

`MappedByteBuffer`, however, only provides methods for 32-bit positions (`get(int index)`, `position(int newPosition)`, etc.), which seems to imply that I cannot map files larger than 2 GB.

How can I get around this limitation?

Comment: You might consider loading your data to a database and do your work from there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at [Using a memory mapped file for a huge matrix](https://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-memory-mapped-file-for-huge.html) code which shows how to create a list of `MappedByteBuffer`, each smaller then 2 GB, to map the entire file:

```
private static final int MAPPING_SIZE = 1 << 30;
...
long size = 8L * width * height;
for (long offset = 0; offset < size; offset += MAPPING_SIZE) {
    long size2 = Math.min(size - offset, MAPPING_SIZE);
    mappings.add(raf.getChannel().map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, offset, size2));
}
```

As per [JDK-6347833 (fs) Enhance MappedByteBuffer to support sizes >2GB on 64 bit platforms](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6347833) the reason for the 2 GB limit is:

> A MappedByteBuffer is a ByteBuffer with additional operations to support memory-mapped file regions. To support mapping a region larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE would require a parallel hierarchy of classes. For now the only solution is create multiple MappedByteBuffers where each corresponds to a region that is no larger than 2GB.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, `MappedByteBuffer` has the 2GB limitation due to usage of integer index/position pointers.

To get around that you could use an alternative implementation like [larray](https://github.com/xerial/larray)